# What exactly is SKEmitterNode particleLifetime?

Tags: ios, xcode, sprite-kit, particles, skemitternode

The documentation for `SKEmitterNode` says that the `particleLifetime` property is:

> The average lifetime of a particle, in seconds.

I am seeing something fishy in xcode 7.2.1, though. As I was trying to modify an explosion emitter, I expected that increasing the particle lifetime value in the editor would make the total size of the explosion bigger... the particles would live longer and thus travel farther. I don't want to increase the speed that they expand, I like the current speed. I just want them to travel farther and create a bigger "blast."

However, instead, what I actually see in xcode is that the explosion remains exactly the same size, but the interval between drawing gets longer. I see that if I adjust the particle lifetime down to, say, 0.5, xcode repeatedly draws the explosion. If I adjust the interval up to, say, 20, xcode draws exactly the same sized explosion, once every ~20 seconds. That wasn't what I was expecting, at all.

I created an emitter via xcode with:

- Texture: spark.png
- Particle birthrate: 5500
- Maximum Particles: 2266
- Angle start: 0
- Angle Range: 360
- Speed: 70
- Acceleration: 0
- Color ramp from white to yellow

And tried the following experiment:

```
-(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

    SKEmitterNode *node = [SKEmitterNode nodeWithFileNamed:@"ExplosionNuke"];
    SKEmitterNode *node2 = [SKEmitterNode nodeWithFileNamed:@"ExplosionNuke"];
    SKEmitterNode *node3 = [SKEmitterNode nodeWithFileNamed:@"ExplosionNuke"];
    SKEmitterNode *node4 = [SKEmitterNode nodeWithFileNamed:@"ExplosionNuke"];

    for (UITouch *touch in touches)
    {
        CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInNode:layerWorld];
        CGPoint left = CGPointMake(touchPoint.x - 100, touchPoint.y);
        CGPoint right = CGPointMake(touchPoint.x + 100, touchPoint.y);
        CGPoint top = CGPointMake(touchPoint.x, touchPoint.y + 100);
        CGPoint bottom = CGPointMake(touchPoint.x, touchPoint.y - 100);

        node.particleLifetime = .10;
        node2.particleLifetime = .99;
        node3.particleLifetime = 1.5;
        node4.particleLifetime = 300;

        node.position = left;
        node2.position = right;
        node3.position = top;
        node4.position = bottom;

        [layerWorld addChild:node4];
        [layerWorld addChild:node3];
        [layerWorld addChild:node2];
        [layerWorld addChild:node];

    }
```

With four nodes bursting on the screen at the same time, the results are:

**For lifetime <= 0.99:** the shape of the entire explosion does indeed change. smaller values travel shorter distances and result in smaller explosions that disappear faster from view.

**for lifetime >= 1.0:** the size of the explosion is capped; any value from 1 to 2,250 creates exactly the same size of explosion that remains visible for exactly the same amount of time. A particle with a lifetime of 2,000 does not remain visible any longer than a particle with a lifetime of 1.0. Also, for any lifetime > 1.00, the particle does not fully complete the color ramp. This emitter ramps from white to yellow. All durations < 1.0 complete the ramp to yellow. All values > 1.0 are noticeably "whiter" (even though they fade from the screen at the same time)

I'm now thoroughly confused as to what `particleLifetime` is supposed to be doing. Only values from 0.0 to 1.0 have make a visible change. the fact that the color ramp isn't completing for durations > 1.0 makes me think the particles know they're supposed to last longer and have more time to change colors. But, they fade from view before that completes.

**What am I doing wrong here? why don't particles in node4 keep moving visibly across--and eventually off--the screen for five minutes? Why do they fade from view at the exact same time as node3?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your emitter's `particleSpeedScale` property is negative, your particles will decrease in size until they are no longer visible before `particleLifetime` seconds have elapsed.

The `particleSpeedScale` property affects

> the rate at which a particle’s scale factor changes per second.

where a positive value increases the size of the particles over time and a negative value decreases the size of the particles.

For example, if the initial particle size is 1 and

```
particleSpeedScale = 0.5
```

the particle's size will be 1.5 after 1 second, 2.25 after 2 seconds, etc.

If the initial particle size is 1 and

```
particleSpeedScale = -0.5
```

the particle's size will be 0.5 after 1 second, 0.25 after 2 seconds, etc.

I suggest you start by setting `particleSpeedScale = 0`. This will cause the size of the particles to remain constant throughout the life cycle. Adjust the property as needed.